# expss R set_caption() not outputting to Excel

Tags: r, expss

Yesterdays print output to Excel script you sent me basically working well. One issue though. I use set_caption() a lot as my clients want the full question wording above each table [the reference to the variable label isn't enough]. When I use set_caption() the Console version shows it correctly, but when I export it to Excel [via the function you sent yesterday] the tables with set_caption() aren't outputted to Excel.

I have tried adding %>% set_caption(xxx) in both the cro and longer piped versions.
I do put this at the end of each line - could this be the problem? All the examples of set_caption() are at the end of the line and this works on Console outputs.
Any ideas on how I can include the full question for each crosstab if set_caption() won't work?
Thanks again & regards. Mark

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't send you anything.

Comment: See update in `new_output` and `stop_output` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471883/expss-exporting-many-tables-to-ms-excel/56473874#56473874  I fixed outputting captioned tables.